# Batch file to install an application package from server to all clients on schedule

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, installation

I am having an application package which I need to install on 500+ users workstations in a production environment.  I don't have any SMS tool or software distribution tool to deploy that I need to do with Windows Server 2003 options only or command-line interface batch file.

Answer (score 1):

If the computers are in your Windows domain, you could use the Software Installation extension  with group policies for automated installations.

This TechNet article explains this technique:

[**How Group Policy Software Installation Extension Works**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782152(WS.10).aspx)

> The Group Policy Software installation
>   extension allows administrators to use
>   the Group Policy Object Editor to
>   centrally manage the installation of
>   software on all client computers in an
>   organization. This is accomplished
>   either by assigning applications to
>   users or computers, or by publishing
>   applications for users.
>
> Software can be assigned on a per-user
>   or per-computer basis when an
>   organization does not want to give
>   users the choice to install or remove
>   the software. For example, if a user
>   removes a user-assigned application by
>   using Add or Remove Programs in
>   Control Panel, the Group Policy
>   Software installation extension
>   automatically reapplies the
>   advertisement information after the
>   user logs on or the computer restarts,
>   and the software is reinstalled the
>   next time a user selects it or tries
>   to open a file with an associated file
>   name extension. It is not possible for
>   a user to delete a computer-assigned
>   application. In most cases, packages
>   that are assigned to users or
>   computers include applications that
>   are essential but do not create
>   congestion between the clients and the
>   software distribution points.

There is another article on TechNet, which explains the basics: [What Is Group Policy Software Installation Extension?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739148(WS.10).aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your other option would be to use Sysinternals (now a part of Microsoft) psexec. It can either run a command remotely on a specified machine or on all machines in a text file. Have the machines either run the installer or a batch file that copies/installs your application.

[PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)